# Cython: double or array as input

Tags: python-3.x, cython

Let's consider the following simple example:

```
def add(double a, double b):
    cdef double c
    c = a + b
    return c
```

How can I define it such that the inputs `a` and `b` (and the output`c` as a consequence) might be double or np.array?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You already declared the input variable type. You can define the return type of your function as: `def <return_type> function_name(double a, double b):`

Answer (score 0):

For 1D NumPy arrays:

```
def add(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] a, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] b):
    cdef np.ndarray [np.float64_t, ndim=1] c
    c = a + b
    return c
```

For 2D NumPy arrays:

```
    def add(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] a, np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] b):
    cdef np.ndarray [np.float64_t, ndim=2] c
    c = a + b
    return c
```

You can see that `ndim` is the number of dimensions. `np.float64_t` is the data type for the array elements, `np.float64`. `np.ndarray` defines the data type as a NumPy array.

For arrays of `double`, you can look into [memoryviews](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#memoryviews), but it might be not what you want. It is for fast indexing, not arithmetic operations.